# Django login/logout

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a login and logout page with django. The problem I have is that when I submit the form, it doesn't go the url which I specified. When I click the login button, I want it to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ but instead, it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/home/.

Below is my login/logout code in my view.py:

```
def login(request):
    def errorHandler(error):
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'error' : error})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                authLogin(request, user)
                fullName = user.get_full_name
                return render_to_response('logged_in.html', {'full_name': fullName})
            else:
                error = 'Account disabled.'
        return errorHandler(error)
        else:
            error = 'Invalid details entered.'
        return errorHandler(error)

    return render_to_response('login.html')

@login_required
def logout(request):
    authLogout(request)
    return render_to_response('logged_in.html')
```

my login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if error %}
    <p><b><font color="red">Error: </font></b>{{ error }}</p>
  {% endif %}

  <form action="/home/" method="post">
    <label for="username">User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

my logged_in.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block name %}{{ full_name }} is {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p><a href='/'>Logout</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

url:

```
(r'^$', 'myapp.views.login'),
(r'^home/$', 'myapp.views.logout'),
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually login the user, the form sends unauthenticated user to `/home/`, which can't process, because it requires login. :-) So it redirects user to login view, storing the destination in `next` parameter.

**Solution**:
`<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: That works. However, since its still http://127.0.0.1:8000 (doesn't change URL), it doesn't actually use the logout view. It just goes to that page. (the logout view is set to /home/)

Comment: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'` in settings.py

Comment: I've tried this before, but the url still remains as 127.0.0.1:8000. Do I have to specify the redirect URL in my view? or could it have something to do with render_to_response? I've tried HttpResponseRedirect, but I need content to passed to the template like you can see in my code currently.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` will have no effect as you don't use built-in `login` view. So it's your task to redirect. If you want to save context between redirects you can use GET parameters, sessions, cookies and so on. By why do you need that? Since logging in, user's object will be accessible from any view (`request.user`). And, by the way, it's much better not to reinvent the wheel and use bult-in views (`django.contrib.auth.views`)

Comment: Yeah, I guess why I'm trying to implement my own login/logout view is because I have no idea how I would display the user's full name while logged in (i.e. welcome, john smith) I've tried doing it like you said: (r'^home/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logged_in.html'}) but I have no idea where to request user information. Would this somehow be done in views? Sorry about this, as you can tell i'm pretty bad with django ;(

Comment: `request.user` will be accessible from any view. To deal only with logged users, use `request.user.is_authenticated()`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I currently have: (r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    (r'^home/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logged_in.html'}). This is based on what you suggested. As you can see the user logs in and is redirected to /home/. So what I'm asking is, how (or where) do I put things on that webpage such as "Welcome, john smith" (with the request.user method) Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand either. :-) Now user 1). opens login url ('/') 2). clicks 'login' 3). is redirected to '/home/' 4). where he logs out immediately. When do you want to show the message? I believe you should add some more urls, now you have two doors, but no rooms to live in. :-)

Comment: I guess I should explain what I'm actually trying to do :). Basically, I'm trying to make a website in which the homepage has a login form and register new user form (not sure i do this yet, that is why I'm trying to do it step by step by first getting login/logout to work) When a enters the details, the user will log in to their homepage (/home/ - note: I tried making it same URL but not quite sure how) this homepage will have several forms such as a table displaying user and friends updates, add update, and the logout form. I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve now :) So any help?

Comment: By the way, think of the website like twitter, that's what I'm kinda trying to create :)

Comment: If you want to display some data at `/home/`, why do you attach `logout` view to it? You should create a view: `def home (request)` with `login_required` decorator. In this view you should get user object:  `user = request.user` Then you should pass it to template: `return direct_to_template(request, 'temlate_name.html', {'user': user})`. Then you will get `{{ user }}` variable in your template and will be able to call its `get_full_name` method. I don't know how to explain it any clearer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. Its just that I want the logout button to be on that page so that when a user is done viewing the page, they can just logout and it will go back to the homepage (no need to go to a specific url to logout). Understand? Again, thanks for your help, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Look at any site in the web. All of them have a specific url to logout. For SO it's `http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout` for example. So you just need a link (or button) to this url somewhere on your page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to remove hidden input with name="next"
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login